# Use robocopy to only copy files not folders

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I am trying to write a script that copies all files in my source folder to another folder but without the folder structure, so just the files.

So far I have:

```
robocopy "<source>" "<target>" /s /copyall
```

Example: I have C:\1\2\3.txt and C:\4\5\6.jpg and in my target I only want D:\target\3.txt and D:\target\6.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you tagged this with Powershell: how about `find-item|copy-item`?

Comment: When flattening a folder structure, what about duplicate file names from different sources?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider unfortunately I can not use those because I need to use some specifications. I didn't mention so in my original post because I wanted to keep my question simple. I need to specify the maxage and filetypes of the files to copy. As far as I've seen that's not possible with find-item.

Comment: @LotPings There aren't duplicate file names.

Comment: Even if get-childitem (not find-item) does not provide parameters for this directly you can easily filter the result with `where` before piping it into `copy`

Comment: Not posted as an answer because I don't know exactly how to do this in powershell but it should be almost trivial to iterate through the directory tree and run, e.g.,  `robocopy "c:\1\2\3" "d:\target" /copyall` for each source directory, just leave out the `/s` option.

Comment: Possibly useful: [long path support in Powershell](https://win32.io/posts/Long-Path-Support-In-Powershell).

Answer (score 4):

As already stated in the comments, you can achieve this easily with Powershell:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter "*.txt" $source |
  Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -gt (get-date -date "2018-12-01 00:00:00") } |
  Copy-Item -Destination $target
```

This runs `Get-ChildItem` recursively, looking only for files matching the filter `*.txt`. Afterwards the result is filtered by the `LastAccessTime` attribute of the file and only files newer than date X are kept. The result of that is piped into `Copy-Item`.

Of course, you can also run robocopy at the end, but that becomes pretty redundant.